# Paypal simple chcekout testing

Tags: paypal

I am new to paypal.. I am trying to implement a simple button that takes my client to paypal - allows him to pay, and then sends him back to my site to either success or failure callback pages.  I also need to pass an identifier in order to use get it back and use it in the callbacks.

I created a button using their UI, and got this:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="$$$$">
                <input type="hidden" name="postId" value="666">
                <input type="image" src="btn_paynowCC_LG.gif"
                             border="0" name="submit">
            </form>
```

I tried adding: return and cancel_return vars. I didn't want to make a purchase yet, but even cancel didn't work. I had to set the urls using their UI. But then I could not get the identifier on cancel.

Can anybody help me? I thought it will be much much much simpler than this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add return and return_cancel var during button creation process.
It is in the step 3, advanced variables.

Comment: Thanks, But how can I add the identifier? lets say that it is book number 5 for example.  I want to pass it and receive it back in my callbacks.